# Jquery - text is on equal to (mail typing error)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>John Vicket</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <td>email@gmail.com</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <td>425 4657 451</td>
  <tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Address</th>
    <td>1st Ave, Nyc</td>
  <tr>

<table>
```

How to detect typing error in email domain? So I need to

1) Ignore username

2) If is domain different that gmail.com, live.com, hotmail.com, yahoo.com etc. display alert

I created some codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxveKp

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly. You want to split the string at the @ sign and have an array of the domains you want to check against.

```
var email = "email@gmail.com"
var parts = email.split("@");
var isMatch = parts.length===2 && ["gmail.com", "live.com", "hotmail.com", "yahoo.com"].indexOf(parts[1].toLowerCase())!==-1;
console.log(isMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is shorter version of @epascarello's answer, just making it getting the directly from the table :

```
var parts = $("th:contains('Email')").next('td').html().split("@");
alert(parts.length===2 && ["gmail.com", "live.com", "hotmail.com","yahoo.com"].indexOf(parts[1].toLowerCase())!==-1 ? "Continue !" : "Sorry !");
```

[Your codepan.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpboRG?editors=1111)